# Google drive & vuejs3 - upload file to a specific folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, google-drive-api, frontend

This is my function to upload the file to google drive:

```
    async processFiles(files) {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("file", files[0])
      formData.append("name", files[0].name)
      formData.append("parents", this.currentFolder.folderId)

      axios
        .post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files", formData, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",

          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
```

the file is uploading to the general google drive and not to the specific folder (this.currentFolder.folderId).
What am I doing wrong here?

I tried some functions already and this is the only one that uploads file to the google drive.

Comment: Have you tried logging with `console.log(this.currentFolder.folderId)` and verified that this folder id exists in google drive? I think it might be empty or invalid.

Comment: I verified it, it's exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async processFiles(files) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", files[0]);
  formData.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: files[0].name, parents: [this.currentFolder.folderId] })], { type: 'application/json' }));
  axios
    .post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files", formData, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}` },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

- When this script is run, the file of `files[0]` is uploaded to Google Drive with the file metadata of `{ name: files[0].name, parents: [this.currentFolder.folderId] }`.
- When a request is run by `multipart/form-data` with `new FormData()`, it is not required to set the content type of the request header. The content type including the boundary is automatically created.
- In order to set the file metadata, I used `formData.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: files[0].name, parents: [this.currentFolder.folderId] })], { type: 'application/json' }));`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `files[0]` is the valid file object and your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive using Drive API. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

`parents` is a list parameter, so you should provide as one in the form field.

Like this:

`formData.append("parents[]", this.currentFolder.folderId)`

Comment: Tried it but still doesn't work, it upload the file but not to the specific folder

Comment: The documentation states clearly: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

parents[]: "If not specified as part of a create request, the file will be placed directly in the user's My Drive folder."

So for some reason it still doesn't pass the parent folder correctly. try inspecting your post data in the network inspector of your browser. It should contain the `parents[]: bwafuejjweaklfjweah3294y23894e` (folder hash) in the payload